# Java RMI: exception: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "127.0.0.1:1099" "connect,resolve")

Tags: java, eclipse, rmi

I am trying to run my first Java RMI client-server app with the following command line input.

> java -cp eclipse-workspace -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:/eclipse-workspace -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost -Djava.security.policy=rmidemo.policy -Djava.security.debug=access ct/ExamEngine

The rmidemo.policy file:

```
grant codeBase "file:/Users/user/eclipse-workspace/rimdemo/src/ct" {
permission java.security.AllPermission;
```

};

The stack trace is:

> access: access allowed ("java.io.FilePermission"
>   "/Users/user/eclipse-workspace" "read") access: access allowed
>   ("java.security.SecurityPermission"
>   "getProperty.networkaddress.cache.ttl") access: access allowed
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "sun.net.inetaddr.ttl" "read") access:
>   access allowed ("java.security.SecurityPermission"
>   "getProperty.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl") access: access
>   allowed ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "com.sun.sdp.conf" "read")
>   access: access allowed ("java.lang.RuntimePermission"
>   "loadLibrary.net") access: access allowed ("java.io.FilePermission"
>   "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libnet.dylib"
>   "read") access: access allowed ("java.lang.RuntimePermission"
>   "modifyThreadGroup") access: access allowed
>   ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup") access: access
>   allowed ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "getClassLoader") access:
>   access allowed ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup")
>   access: access allowed ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThread")
>   access: access allowed ("java.lang.RuntimePermission"
>   "setContextClassLoader") access: access allowed
>   ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThread") access: access allowed
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "sun.rmi.dgc.logLevel" "read") access:
>   access allowed ("java.util.logging.LoggingPermission" "control")
>   access: access allowed ("java.util.logging.LoggingPermission"
>   "control") access: access allowed ("java.util.PropertyPermission"
>   "java.rmi.dgc.leaseValue" "read") access: access allowed
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "sun.rmi.dgc.checkInterval" "read")
>   access: access allowed ("java.util.logging.LoggingPermission"
>   "control") access: access allowed
>   ("java.util.logging.LoggingPermission" "control") access: access
>   allowed ("java.util.PropertyPermission"
>   "sun.rmi.runtime.schedulerThreads" "read") access: access allowed
>   ("java.lang.RuntimePermission"
>   "sun.rmi.runtime.RuntimeUtil.getInstance") access: access allowed
>   ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "getProtectionDomain") access: access
>   allowed ("java.util.PropertyPermission"
>   "jdk.internal.lambda.dumpProxyClasses" "read") access: access allowed
>   ("java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission" "suppressAccessChecks") access:
>   access allowed ("java.util.PropertyPermission"
>   "sun.rmi.transport.dgcFilter" "read") access: access allowed
>   ("java.security.SecurityPermission"
>   "getProperty.sun.rmi.transport.dgcFilter") access: access allowed
>   ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "setContextClassLoader") access: access
>   allowed ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.rmi.server.hostname"
>   "read") access: access allowed ("java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission"
>   "suppressAccessChecks") access: access allowed
>   ("java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission" "suppressAccessChecks") access:
>   access allowed ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "setContextClassLoader")
>   access: access allowed ("java.lang.RuntimePermission"
>   "getClassLoader") access: access allowed
>   ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup") access: access
>   allowed ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThread") access: access
>   allowed ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "setContextClassLoader")
>   access: access allowed ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThread")
>   access: access allowed ("java.lang.RuntimePermission"
>   "modifyThreadGroup") access: access allowed
>   ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup") access: access
>   allowed ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThread") access: access
>   allowed ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThread") access: access
>   allowed ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThread") access: access
>   allowed ("java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission" "suppressAccessChecks")
>   access: access allowed ("java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission"
>   "suppressAccessChecks") access: access allowed
>   ("java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission" "suppressAccessChecks") access:
>   access allowed ("java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission"
>   "suppressAccessChecks") access: access denied
>   ("java.net.SocketPermission" "MacBook-Pro.local" "resolve")
>   java.lang.Exception: Stack trace  at
>   java.lang.Thread.dumpStack(Thread.java:1336)  at
>   java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:462)
>     at
>   java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884)
>     at
>   java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
>     at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkConnect(SecurityManager.java:1048)
>     at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1477)     at
>   java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry.getRegistry(LocateRegistry.java:158)
>     at
>   java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry.getRegistry(LocateRegistry.java:123)
>     at
>   java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry.getRegistry(LocateRegistry.java:75)
>     at ct.ExamEngine.main(ExamEngine.java:64) access: access allowed
>   ("java.security.SecurityPermission" "getPolicy") access: access
>   allowed ("java.io.FilePermission" "/Users/user/eclipse-workspace"
>   "read") access: domain that failed ProtectionDomain 
>   (file:/Users/user/eclipse-workspace/ ) 
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@2a139a55   
>   java.security.Permissions@27bc2616 (  ("java.net.SocketPermission"
>   "localhost:0" "listen,resolve")  ("java.io.FilePermission"
>   "/Users/user/eclipse-workspace/-" "read") 
>   ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "exitVM") 
>   ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "stopThread") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.specification.version" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.version" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "os.arch" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.specification.vendor" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vm.specification.name" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vm.vendor" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "path.separator" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "os.version" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "file.separator" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "line.separator" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vm.specification.vendor" "read")
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.specification.name" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vendor.url" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vendor" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vm.version" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vm.name" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vm.specification.version"
>   "read")  ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "os.name" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.class.version" "read") )
>
> access: access allowed ("java.util.PropertyPermission"
>   "java.rmi.server.hostname" "read") access: access allowed
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "sun.rmi.transport.connectionTimeout"
>   "read") access: access allowed ("java.util.PropertyPermission"
>   "sun.rmi.transport.tcp.handshakeTimeout" "read") access: access
>   allowed ("java.util.PropertyPermission"
>   "sun.rmi.transport.tcp.responseTimeout" "read") access: access allowed
>   ("java.lang.RuntimePermission"
>   "sun.rmi.runtime.RuntimeUtil.getInstance") access: access allowed
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "jdk.net.ephemeralPortRange.low"
>   "read") access: access allowed ("java.lang.RuntimePermission"
>   "loadLibrary.net") access: access allowed ("java.io.FilePermission"
>   "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libnet.dylib"
>   "read") access: access allowed ("java.util.PropertyPermission"
>   "os.name" "read") access: access allowed
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "jdk.net.ephemeralPortRange.high"
>   "read") access: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission"
>   "127.0.0.1:1099" "connect,resolve") java.lang.Exception: Stack trace
>     at java.lang.Thread.dumpStack(Thread.java:1336)     at
>   java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:462)
>     at
>   java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884)
>     at
>   java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
>     at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkConnect(SecurityManager.java:1051)
>     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:584)     at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)  at
>   java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:434)   at
>   java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:211)   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:148)
>     at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
>     at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:338)   at
>   sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(RegistryImpl_Stub.java:147)
>     at ct.ExamEngine.main(ExamEngine.java:65) access: access allowed
>   ("java.security.SecurityPermission" "getPolicy") access: access
>   allowed ("java.io.FilePermission" "/Users/user/eclipse-workspace"
>   "read") access: domain that failed ProtectionDomain 
>   (file:/Users/user/eclipse-workspace/ ) 
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@2a139a55   
>   java.security.Permissions@4fca772d (  ("java.net.SocketPermission"
>   "localhost:0" "listen,resolve")  ("java.io.FilePermission"
>   "/Users/user/eclipse-workspace/-" "read") 
>   ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "exitVM") 
>   ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "stopThread") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.specification.version" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.version" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "os.arch" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.specification.vendor" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vm.specification.name" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vm.vendor" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "path.separator" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "os.version" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "file.separator" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "line.separator" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vm.specification.vendor" "read")
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.specification.name" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vendor.url" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vendor" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vm.version" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vm.name" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vm.specification.version"
>   "read")  ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "os.name" "read") 
>   ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.class.version" "read") )
>
> ExamEngine exception: java.security.AccessControlException: access
>   denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "127.0.0.1:1099"
>   "connect,resolve")    at
>   java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
>     at
>   java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884)
>     at
>   java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
>     at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkConnect(SecurityManager.java:1051)
>     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:584)     at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)  at
>   java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:434)   at
>   java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:211)   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:148)
>     at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
>     at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:338)   at
>   sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(RegistryImpl_Stub.java:147)
>     at ct.ExamEngine.main(ExamEngine.java:65)

[EDIT] If it wasn't already clear the issue lies with the security manager, when I removed it, it worked, but it is necessary for this app, so I need to figure out a way around this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

Start the RMI Registry

`rmiregistry &`

To Start the server (don't forget the "&" at end so it runs in background)

**Note:** When the codebase property value is set to the URL of a directory, the value must be terminated by a "/".

`-Djava.security.policy=/Users/user/eclipse-workspace/rimdemo/src/ct/rmidemo.policy -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:/Users/user/eclipse-workspace/rimdemo/src/ct/`

To start a client

`-Djava.security.policy=/Users/user/eclipse-workspace/rimdemo/src/ct/rmidemo.policy`

Your server policy should be:

> grant {
>
> permission java.security.AllPermission;
>
> };

Your client policy should be:

> grant {
>
> permission java.security.AllPermission;
>
> };

**Note:** you can likely just use the same policy file for both client and server.  Also note, your classpath needs to be the root directory of your class file tree

Comment: Sorry my command line caused that for some reason. I used the same parms as you mentioned above but it causes that error.

Comment: I'm headed home back can try and research a little more tomorrow!  Let me know if you get it working, I do recall someone else being fixed by making sure they were running the code within same folder as the class files.

Comment: I was able to get it running by removing the security manager but unfortunately it is necessary for this project.

Comment: @ConorNaylor, thanks for marking it as correct - I take it it worked?

Comment: I just got it working today, after some more grievance. Your answer is correct, but I still managed to make a mess of it. Thanks

Comment: ROFL, sorry about that - At least its almost Happy Hour somewhere!  Actually you're in Ireland - well its definitely past happy hour!  Cheers Mate!  Glad you got it.